# Como saber si se hacen cambios en páginas o entradas de Wordpress con git?

Tags: wordpress, git

Estoy intentando implementar git en Wordpress. He instalado algún plugin para ello, como VersionPress y Revisr, pero con VersionPress no se puede subir el repositorio a bitbucket o github, y con Revisr no puedo saber los cambios de entradas y páginas.

Alguien sabe cómo podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 2):

VersionPress sí permite subir el repo a github. En la [documentación](https://blog.versionpress.net/2015/05/versionpress-1-0-walkthrough/) aparece:

> I can do branching / merging, I can push the repo to sites like GitHub
>   or BitBucket, there are really no limits.

Es cierto que el panel de administración de VersionPress no te ofrece la opción de apuntar a un repo en github o bitbucket, pero claro que puedes hacerlo por línea de comando

Suponiendo ya tienes VersionPress andando, el paso siguiente es crearte en github un repo vacío para subir tu blog. Supongamos que lo llamaste:

```
https://github.com/JonJauregi/mi_blog
```

La ruta (ssh) al repo sería

```
git@github.com:JonJauregi/mi_blog.git
```

Sabiendo eso, te mueves a la ruta raíz de tu blog y añades el repo como remoto. La convención es que el remoto se llame `origin

```
cd /var/www/blog
git remote add origin git@github.JonJauregi/mi_blog.git
```

De ahí en adelante sólo **necesitas configurar un cronjob** que periódicamente ejecute

```
cd /var/www/blog && git push origin master -f
```

Añadí la -f para forzar la subida a github, puesto que según lo que veo VersionPress te permite hacer `undo` y `rollback`, operaciones que por debajo seguramente ejecutan un `rebase`.

Para manejar tu repo usando ssh (y por lo tanto hacer automática la subida periódica) tienes que [generar una llave RSA y añadir la llave pública a tu cuenta en github](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/).

Nota: todo esto es válido para linux. En windows sería igual el comando para añadir el remoto, pero el tema de autenticarse mediante llave ssh no sabría hacerlo.